# Android Studio: debugger unusable when inspecting coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, debugging, kotlin-coroutines

this has been asked before but none of the solution proposed solve this.
I'm on Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 RC 3, and when I have a breakpoint which runs inside a coroutine, it becomes impossible to use the debugger.
Either the debugger is stuck on evaluating variable saying "collecting data..." or when setting certain options, it shows the data but when trying to resume the executions, the whole app freezes and only thing I can do is restart, making impossible to test anything.

Is there any solution to this? I had this problem forever, no matter the version.
I tried the common settings proposed in other questions to no avail:
debugger->data view-> show values inline
debugger->data view->java->enable toString() object view

The only useful thing is to flip debugger->disable coroutine agent which unfreezes the app and resume execution, but the debugger detach itself, so it's not a solution for any time-sensitive debugging.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Same here, the debugger and coroutines does not work well together, i suggest you using the Logcat to be able to debug your async code.